# Actual Values not selected in the Inline Popup Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I am using x-editable jQuery plugin for inline editing of values. Editing and remote call and saving in DB and others works fine as expected.

The only problem I face is that when I click the item to edit, the popup with the selectbox appears as expected. But the value is empty in the popup.

If I edit the value and save it and reopen again, the value is shown.. but not when there are no changes made.

What should I do to make sure that when the popup opens for editing, the present value should be already present.

**Below is the part of HTML code snippet:**

```
<a href="#" class="position" data-pk="7">Bottom</a>
<a href="#" class="position" data-pk="8">Top</a>
```

**Below is the part of jQuery code snippet:**

```
$('.position').editable({
    type: 'select',
    name: 'position',
    url: '/save.php',
    source: [{
        value: 'left',
        text: 'Left'
    }, {
        value: 'right',
        text: 'Right'
    }, {
        value: 'top',
        text: 'Top'
    }, {
        value: 'bottom',
        text: 'Bottom'
    }]
});
```

All examples in the site uses mockjax which I am not sure whether to use in a live site.

**[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Purus/zXQbe/)**

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: I tried that and facing some issues as my data is very dynamic. Could not able to make one due to this reason. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Nouphal.M: Fiddle has been added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zXQbe/4/

It came down to your markup. Should be the following:

```
<a href="#" class="position" data-pk="7" data-value="bottom">Bottom</a>
<a href="#" class="position" data-pk="8" data-value="top">Top</a>
```

*Edit:* Realized I clobbered over the `data-pk` values you had defined.